# Moving data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently moving data between sheet 1 and sheet 2. Sheet 1 contains averages of items. BN/BO columns contain the averages. It passes the forumula instead of the average number. Any fix to this using the method I am using without using a new method like `=Sheet2!B2`?

```
Dim Lastrow2 As Integer
Lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:K" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BN4:BN" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BO4:BO" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2")
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D" & Lastrow2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Look into PasteSpecial

Comment: Just set the two ranges equal `Range([range where I want data copied **to**).Value = Range([range where I want to copy data **from**).Value`.  This helps too because you avoid using the clipboard.

Comment: @BruceWayne 's method is what I would recommend too. It's a good practice to get into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing your method for performance reasons (avoiding the Clipboard is more performant), but if you want to use the same method, you can use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:K" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BN4:BN" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BO4:BO" & Lastrow2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```