# How can I copy a range of cells based on a Header to paste to another worksheet and match the headers?

Tags: vba, excel

I need a code to copy a range of cells (`H21:H38`) from my source worksheet (`Acct Total`) to a corresponding column on my target worksheet (`COS% Tracking`) based on matching headers. But the hiccup I have is that the header is in cell A6 on my source worksheet (`Acct Total`). I've researched it a bit and I've found this code that worked for someone else:

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

So my issue is that I don't know where to begin to edit this code to work like I need. This code worked by using the header above the range of cells but that won't do in my case. I'll attach pictures so that hopefully I'm not too vague.

[image: Acct Total Tab]

[image: COS% Tracking Tab]

Can someone help me to edit this code according to my needs?

Edit: Additional Picture for the source of the dates.
[GL Code Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T5rT.png)

Comment: ` based on matching headers` does not actually explain which column you would like to copy into.  .... also, please indent all your code 4 more spaces

Comment: Are these worksheets in the same workbook and is the header match based on matching dates and are these formatted as dates? Also, is the source range always H21:H38?

Comment: Did you consider using formulas instead?

Comment: @AntiDrondert yes i have, but i need it to be fool proof (yes i know i used the wrong "Full"). The goal is to add this code to the existing macro "Begin New Period" so that at the start of the week when that button is pressed the information will be copied to the tracking tab and stay there for the whole year. i'm afraid someone will change the period week to the wrong week in cell A6 and screw up the tracking tab. Yes i realize that can also happen with the macro if the date is incorrect before executing the macro. But i'm praying that doesn't happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following construct as a starting point for a different way to solve the same problem. There are descriptive variables so you have an idea of what is happening.

Edit: As the target sheet row 3 is locked, code has been amended to use Match function to return column number where string is found (if found).

Essentially:

Set your source and target worksheets.

```
Set sourceWorksheet = wb.Sheets("Acct Total")
Set targetWorksheet = wb.Sheets("COS% Tracking")
```

Define your target value (the date you are trying to match on) and source range

```
targetDate = Trim$(sourceWorksheet.Range("A6"))
Set sourceRange = sourceWorksheet.Range("H21:H38")
```

Find the column number of where value (targetDate) is present in the target sheet

```
colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(targetDate, searchRange, 0)
```

Add error handling in case it is not present i.e. if date (as string) is not found....

```
ErrHand: 'code in this section.....
```

Set the address of where the target data will be pasted

```
Set targetRange = .Range(Cells(4, colNum), Cells(21, colNum))
```

Set the target range to be equal to the source range.

```
targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value
```

Adapt as appropriate.

Putting it together you getting something along the lines of the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copydata()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetDate As String
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWorksheet = wb.Sheets("Acct Total")
    Set targetWorksheet = wb.Sheets("COS% Tracking")
    targetDate = Trim$(sourceWorksheet.Range("A6"))
    Set sourceRange = sourceWorksheet.Range("H21:H38")
    Set searchRange = targetWorksheet.Rows(3)

    On Error GoTo ErrHand

    Dim colNum As Long    
    colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(targetDate, searchRange, 0)

    With targetWorksheet
        Set targetRange = .Range(Cells(4, colNum), Cells(21, colNum))
        targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value
    End With

ErrHand:

    If Err = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Not found: " & targetDate
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

See the following:

[Finding address of text in worksheet](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/49798-return-address-of-cell-containing-specific-text-string?t=58543)

[Moving data between sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533967/moving-data-from-sheet-1-to-sheet-2)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156196/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-how-can-i-copy-a-range-of-cells-based-on-a-header). Additional information should be edited into the question or answer, as appropriate.